# How do I un-gzip data captured by Wireshark?

Tags: windows, wireshark, sniffing

I have a Wireshark capture file with a HTTP request, however, the request is gzipped.

My question is how can I ungzip it so see what data was transfered in cleartext?

The capture file is here if anyone is interested: http://datanethost.net/superuser/log.cap

For inquiring minds, it **is** a request from malware, but I am curious to see what it was "talking" about. I know who it was "talking" to, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can figure, the TCP packets in frames 78 through 89 appear to be [encrypted](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~scott/mat331.fall98/unix/node15.html), [Tor communication](http://www.torproject.org/overview.html).

<sup>That is quite regular for malware that does not want you to know what it calls 'home' (which is almost all Malware).</sup>

Comment: Thats interesting, because it seems on every reboot it appears trying to communicate to muza-flowers.biz not a random host like the Tor project tries to do. It is REALLY odd, because in the HTTP header the host is muza-flowers.biz, but the IP its communicating with is not the A record for muza-flowers.biz.